# New to typescript, is my AMD understanding correct?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I am new to typescript (and javascript for that matter). I put together a tiny test to see if I can do the following based on reading up on AMD, looking at JS based requires and looking at the TS doc.

- Two namespaces Foo & Test
- Import the test namespace
- Create an instance definition
- Create a singleton

**Test.ts**

```
 export class TestClass {
     constructor() {
     }

     testMethod(): void {
     }
 }

 export function Singleton(): void {
 }
```

**Foo.ts**

```
 import Test = require('Test');

 export class Bar {
     private instance = new Test.TestClass();
     private singleton = Test.Singleton;

     constructor() {
         this.instance.testMethod();
         this.singleton();
     }
 }
```

**Generated JS**

```
// Foo.js
define(["require", "exports", 'Test'], function(require, exports, __Test__) {
    var Test = __Test__;

    var Bar = (function () {
        function Bar() {
            this.instance = new Test.TestClass();
            this.singleton = Test.Singleton;
            this.instance.testMethod();
            this.singleton();
        }
        return Bar;
    })();
    exports.Bar = Bar;
});

// Test.js
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    var TestClass = (function () {
        function TestClass() {
        }
        TestClass.prototype.testMethod = function () {
        };
        return TestClass;
    })();
    exports.TestClass = TestClass;

    function Singleton() {
    }
    exports.Singleton = Singleton;
});
```

Based on my code above, is my list of what I wanted to do correct? If so YAY, if not I think I may have missunderstood something about AMD :(

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not homework, sadly that part of my life is only a distant memory!

Comment: As an addendum to the below reference, have a look at this post: http://www.esimov.com/2012/12/typescript-first-impressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of AMD is immaculate. However your understanding of the singleton pattern is incorrect. Have a look at this for an example : http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-singleton-pattern/

Comment: Cheers, I think singleton was a poor choice on my part, I'm still trying to put a name to functions that exist on their own.

Comment: How about "functions"? :-D

Comment: function by purpose `function doSomeAwesome()`